# Django DRF: save data in different models in a single request

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

Lets say I have two models such as

```
class A(models.Model):
    field_1 = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
    field_2 = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)

class B(models.Model):
    field_1 = models.ForeignKey(A, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    field_2 = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
```

I need to write a view and serializer with three fields . Save 2 fields on model A, then the primary key of the saved data on model B along with third field data. Can someone tell me how can I get this done.Iam using django 2.7.

Comment: you can override the create function of class A. can you post your view code, used to create an object of class A for specifics?

Comment: I havent created it yet. I dont know how to make it this way. I am just a beginner to django

Comment: Then, View a Django Tutorial. It will be very difficult to guide you through the whole process